# How does union(sum type) affect struct(product type)? Would that be a product type after containing union?

Tags: c++

I was recently reading an article about `std::variant`, where it was explained that `std::variant` was motivated by the fact that `union` is a sum type but unfortunately, `union` isn't type safe.

I found the following phrase in one of the [articles](https://hsf-training.github.io/hsf-training-cpp-webpage/91-sum-types/index.html#sum-types-in-the-standard-library):

> In C++, product types are well represented by structs and unions

In that case, my first question is whether or not the above phrase is correct? Is it really necessary to have unions for product types(In other words, why do we need a union to make a product type)?

It broke my beliefs about products and sum types, so let me give a definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).(To me, these are two distinct types)

> Two common classes of algebraic types are product types (i.e., tuples and records) and sum types (i.e., tagged or disjoint unions, coproduct types or variant types)

Let's take a look at the following structure, which is trying to make a tagged union!

```
struct Setting {
    union {
       string str;
       int num;
       bool b;
    };
    enum Type { Str , Int , Bool };
    Type tag;
};
```

In this case, what can we say about the type of the `Setting`? Is it a product type after containing union(Or in this case are we creating a complex type)?

Comment: `std::variant` works for non `POD` types, `union` have a lot of limitations, or even if it accepts some non POD it may crash, as for that question for me it looks like a product type with two members, the `union` overlapped member (which probably will be the string since I think it's the biggest)  and the tag. So look at it like a `struct` with a string and an `enum` member. But such opinion may be debated by others.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov, Thanks, Regarding the second question, I agree with you (but I wanted to confirm with the community).
Regarding the first question, I think that since the union is just a type, the fact that the struct is product type may not be impacted(However, I'm not sure, It's a simple question from a programming point of view, but maybe there is some aspect I didn't notice)

Comment: You are asking if a "pre alpha" lession has errors?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I just has some struggle with the quote that `In C++, product types are well represented by structs and unions`, could we delete `unions` in here?(or maybe I'm overthinking over this matter :-)

Comment: Yes that looks like a typo.  Probably originally said sum and product.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I thought about it for a few hours (and it doesn't make sense) and couldn't confirm it myself. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.